# Regex count number of digits excluding space

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that will validate the following condition:

1. Contains only numbers
2. Only single space between numbers are allowed
3. Total digits excluding spaces must be between 16 to 19

Here is the regular expression I have so far :

```
^[0-9]+( [0-9]+)*$
```

Basically I got condition (1) and (2) so I really really need help for (3). Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's simpler than you're making it; you require 16-19 numbers, each of which can optionally have a space preceding it, except the first. So you're looking for a number followed by `{15,18}` numbers preceded by an optional space.

Comment: Where are you using this? e.g. Is it in a programming context where a simple function call to check the numbers could happen as a second step? Also pertinent is the dialect of regex, so again, where are you using this?

Comment: Is the space optional? Is `1` 16 times valid?

Comment: I am using this on PHP to check user input and warn them if it is not the correct format of a credit card number. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Piece of cake.

```
^\d( ?\d){15,18}$
```

Only thing worth remarking on is that `{15,18}` needs to be one less -- the first `\d` already ate a digit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do the trick:

```
^[0-9]( ?[0-9]){15}( ?[0-9])?( ?[0-9])?( ?[0-9])?$
```

I don't know what regexp engine you're using. If it doesn't support {15} then you
will have to repeat the expression before 15 times - which isn't pretty, so if possible
you should use an engine with support for that.

Most unix utilities (like sed,grep and so on either has a (not standardized) switch for
extended regexp support, or alternate executables (like egrep).

Comment: sorry, I didn't indent the code, so stackoverflow reformatted (that is, completely changed) the expression. Fixed now.