# How to check if a string contains more than one numbers (java)?

Tags: java, regex, string

i want an if condition that is only true if a string contains more that four digits in  it , and is false if string has less than four digits in it, i have tried regex like /\d{4}/, need help

Comment: @kruti Your possible duplicate isn't a duplicate at all

Comment: "No luck" is not an adequate description of the problems you encountered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex count number of digits excluding space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978695/regex-count-number-of-digits-excluding-space)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String toCheck1 = "assg3asgasgas123aassag3";
    String toCheck2 = "aasdasfasfs";
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", toCheck1, moreThen4NumbersInString(toCheck1)));
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", toCheck2, moreThen4NumbersInString(toCheck2)));
}

private static boolean moreThen4NumbersInString(String string) {
    int numberOfNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
            numberOfNumbers++;
            if (numberOfNumbers > 4) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:

> more then 4 number in "assg3asgasgas123aassag3" - true more then 4
>   number in "aasdasfasfs" - false

Comment: Unnecessary to go on counting after threshold has been reached ... (just saying)

Comment: @Fildor fixed that

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern will match strings that contain at least 4 digits:

```
(.*?\d){4, }
```

Comment: No, its a regex pattern. How to integrate it in Java shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `string` to a `char[]`. `for`-loop through all the elements of the array and count the digits number in an `int count`. As simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Your expression requires four digit in sequence. There my be some other chars between the digits, so request "digit and optional something" at least four times:

```
(?:\d.*?){4,}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kZ7iZ9/2

Comment: The ".*?" must preceed the digit

Comment: @RafaelAlbert, should work either way but `\d.*?` seems to be more performance effective

Comment: Depends on whether the pattern must match at the beginning or not and therefore on the method used.

Comment: The OP asks for four digits without specifying any position conditions. And the `(?:\d.*?){4,}` pattern does not imply any -- there're no `^` anchor

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for a sample:

```
package com.company.misc;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(.*?\\d){4,}"; 
        //(.*?\d){4, } do not use this, compilation error
        String input = "test2531";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        boolean isMatched = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println(isMatched);

    }
}
```

Hope I have given example to your use case.